# SQL Server restorig backup on Developement (Or Test) Server and user mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I got 3 server.

1. development (my local development machine)
2. Test purpose (Beta site).
3. Production

I got Instances in both SQL server 2005 and 2008.

So, When I want updated data, i take the latest backup from our production server and restore it on the Test or development Server. I got a script that make the changes (restore the file and make some slight changes on the databases.)

My problem is, each time i do this, The SQL server Login (created on the server) I use lose it's Database user mapping. I got to delete it form the restored database and recreate it from the root Security Logins.

Is there a way to include that in my restore script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I got to delete it form the
>   restored database and recreate it from
>   the root Security Logins.*

No, you don't need to do this - at least not on SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

What you need to do (like in a script) is this:

```
USE (your database)
GO

ALTER USER YourUserNo1 WITH LOGIN = YourServerLoginNo1
```

That associates your user `YourUserNo1` in your database `(whatever)` to the server login called `YourServerLoginNo1`.

Works pretty nice'n'easy, I'd say! You can even do this as a last step in the restore script (which I'm sure you have to restore those things over and over again)

Answer (score -1):

When restoring our production database to the report server each month, I run:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'usernamegoeshere'
```

Comment: from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) : Maps an existing database user to a SQL Server login. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. **Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER USER instead.**